# which one is more correct?has/had to have been

Tags: grammar

> If he found the knife that quickly, then it … to have been on the
>   kitchen table

which one is correct? Has / had? Or maybe both?

Comment: "must" is more common than "have to" when it comes to stating the likelihood of how something might have happened in the past. "If he found the knife that quickly, then it must have been on the kitchen table."

Answer (score 1):

**Had to have been** or **Must have been**

Answer (score 1):

"had".  had can be a past tense verb i.e. "I had hair when I was 20" or a past participle, "if I had jumped, I'd be dead now".

When its a past hypothetical its "had"

Comment: You might want to fix the word “pasted”